# Why does empty project have large memory allocation?

Tags: java, android, memory

I created an empty project in android.  Then I ran it with an emulator that has hardware acceleration.
[image]

50% is already allocated.  and of those the smallest free chunk of memory is a measly 174 KB.

Why is this?

Comment: Good question, perhaps it's 1) for the java virtual machine 2) for the android firmware/software/etc that always has to be run? But I am interested in seeing the answers

Answer (score 2):

Because the VM hasnt allocated more. If your memory footprint grows so will your heap size. If I remember correctly hardware acceleration also pulls some part of the renderer into your process which is why as much as 2.5 MB is already used.

> By rendering all of an app’s animations and UI with the GPU, the
>   system takes a hit to memory usage. Loading up the OpenGL drivers for
>   each process takes memory usage of roughly 2MB,

http://www.extremetech.com/computing/107995-the-truth-about-hardware-acceleration-on-android